# When popping a page, automatically pushes to the page in iOS

Tags: angular, typescript, ionic-framework, ionic3

I have a list of items. Each item has an id. So, when you click an item, it pushes to a page with the details of that item. But when I go back, sometimes it pushes to the details page with no id, producing an error because it is not possible to get any information.

I have tried to change the navController lifecycle events. I am currently using `ionViewDidEnter` to load the list of items and `ngOnInit` when pushing to the details page.

Loading the list of items:

```
public ionViewDidEnter() {
  if (this.role === "passenger") {
    this.getCurrentPosition();
  }
}

private getCurrentPosition() {
  const loading = this.loadingCtrl.create({
    content: "Obteniendo ubicación actual...",
    spinner: "dots",
  });

  loading.present();

  // Geolocation options
  const positionOptions = {
    enableHighAccuracy: true,
    maximumAge: 600000,
    timeout: 8000,
  };

  // Get current position
  this.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(positionOptions).then((position) => {

    // Get current position in google maps coords format
    this.originCoords = new google.maps.LatLng(
      position.coords.latitude,
      position.coords.longitude);

    this.getNearbyJourneys();

    // Hide loading toast
    loading.dismiss();

  }).catch(() => {
    loading.dismiss().then(() => {
      this.showErrorAlert("Error al obtener la ubicación");
    }); 
 }); 
}

private getNearbyJourneys() {
  const body = {
    lat: this.originCoords.lat(),
    lng: this.originCoords.lng(),
    token: this.userToken,
  };

  this.journey.listJourneysByOrigin(body).subscribe((d: any) => {
    this.dataTrips = [];
    this.items = d[0];
    for (let i = 0; i < this.journeysToLoad; i++) {
      if (d[0][i] != null) {
        this.dataTrips.push(d[0][i]);
      }
    }
  });
}
```

Details page:

```
public ngOnInit() {
  this.showLoading().then(() => {
    this.getToken().then(() => {
      this.getJourneyInfo(this.userToken).then(() => {
        this.initMap().then(() => {
          this.loading.dismiss();
        }).catch((error) => {
          this.loading.dismiss().then(() => {
            this.showAlertConfirm(
              "Vale",
              error,
              false,
            );
          });
        });
      });
    });
  });
}

private getToken(): Promise<any> {
  return new Promise<any>((resolve) => {
    this.tokenProvider.getToken().then((tkn: any) => {
      this.userToken = tkn;
      resolve();
    }, (error: any) => {
      this.errorHandler(error);
    });
  });
}

private getJourneyInfo(tkn: string): Promise<any> {
  return new Promise<any>((resolve) => {
    this.journey.getJourneyInfo(this.tripID, tkn).subscribe((data: any) => {
      this.initializeValues(data);
      resolve();
    }, () => {
      this.showAlertConfirm(
        "Vale",
        "No ha sido posible obtener la información",
        true);
    });
  });
}

private initMap(): Promise<any> {
  return new Promise<any>((resolve, reject) => {
    this.plt.ready().then(() => {
      const mapOptions = this.gmapsProvider.initMapOptions()

      this.map = new google.maps.Map(this.mapElement.nativeElement, mapOptions);

      this.gmapsProvider.codeAddress(
        this.journeyInfo.origin.direction,
        this.originIcon,
        this.map,
      );

      this.gmapsProvider.codeAddress(
        this.journeyInfo.destination.direction,
        this.destinationIcon,
        this.map,
      );

      this.gmapsProvider.calculateRouteAndDisplay(
        this.map,
        this.journeyInfo.origin.direction,
        this.journeyInfo.destination.direction,
      ).then(() => {
        resolve();
      }).catch((error) => {
        reject(error);
      });
    });
  });
}
```

Comment: Can you be a little more clear about "sometimes it pushes to the details page with no id" - can you give the exact error messages you receive? And by "go back" what exactly do you mean - did you push the back button in your browser/device?

Comment: Also it would be helpful if you could remove anything which isn't essential to reproduce the issue. Try to create a minimal example and post on stackblitz

Comment: It only happens in iOS. I don't know the exact error. When I press the back button, it does the push() action to the journey details page. The error that appears is the one in the getJourneyInfo() function: "No ha sido posible obtener la información". This is because there is no tripID. The push() action it's done when you click an item from the list. Each one has an ID.

Comment: You cannot ask people on StackOverflow to help you solve an error if you don't know what the error is.

Comment: The error is that it automatically pushes to the page without touching anything